# -bash: mysql: command not found

Tags: mysql, localhost

I'm kinda new to this but I am having issues with PHPMyAdmin as well as MySQL on my local machine. It has worked previously.

When I try to run `mysql` from the command line I get:

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

Additionally, PHPMyAdmin will not let me sign in either.

I don't know where to start looking to solve either of these issues. Please help.

Comment: Can you find the mysql installation?

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser.com. Which linux distro are you running (Ubuntu? SUSE? etc etc)

Comment: Is the mysql daemon running? Try the command 'ps agx | grep mysqld'

Comment: @David,even if the daemon is not running,its mysql client which will err not bash

Comment: @David @Neeraj I get this:
   92   ??  S      0:00.02 /bin/sh ./bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/anonymous.bangmarketing.local.pid
  143   ??  S      0:03.68 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --user=mysql --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/anonymous.bangmarketing.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/anonymous.bangmarketing.local.pid
21608 s000  R+     0:00.01 grep mysqld

What does that mean? I am running Mac OSX 10.5.8

Comment: It means that the daemon is running. We know then that mysql is correctly installed.

Comment: How do I check that?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the place your mysql binary is present doesnt happens to be in the PATH environment variable. If you know where it is installed, do
`export PATH="$PATH:/location of binary"`
If you want to do it permanently, add this statement in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks for the help. How do I find out what the path of binary is?

Comment: If you installed MySQL from the .dmg downloaded from mysql.com, the path is usually /usr/local/mysql/bin/

Comment: am I doing this correctly?

pwd: ~ : export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
> ~/.bashrc
>

Comment: I have to ctrl + c to get out of that command. Should typing mysql at this point work now? If so doesn't.

Comment: No, you should open ~/.bashrc with a text editor like vim and paste there the command 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin'

Comment: You're also forgetting to close the double quote. Run this: 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin'(without single quotes) and add the same line in .bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from [MySQL's additional notes section of their online documentation for OS X](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-installation-macosx-notes.html):

- You might want to add aliases to your shell's resource file to make it easier to access commonly used programs such as mysql and mysqladmin  from the command line. The syntax for bash  is:

> ```
> alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
> alias mysqladmin=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
> ```

Comment: This worked on Weezy for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu there is a meta package named "mysql-client". Install that and mysql client utility should be there.

Comment: Does not work with Ubuntu 16.04